# Trouble in changing canvas size using css. The code I used is given below. Someone help me out

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

Am newbie to html. I need to change the size of the cavas using css. I tried this code. but its not working on hover. pls someone help me out. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
canvas:hover
{
id: mycanvas;
width: 400;
height: 400;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're even here still, I suggest you read my comment to your selected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width` and `height` attributes from the `<canvas>` tag.

Change the:

```
canvas:hover
{
id: mycanvas;
width: 400;
height: 400;
}
```

To:

```
canvas#mycanvas:hover
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s34Lh/1/)! Enjoy! Remove the `width` and `height` from the element! And also add `px`!

Comment: Thanks praveen. pls update the naswer in the answer area so that i will set it as accepted answer

Comment: I would not recommend completely removing the width and height attributes from the canvas...  Those define the workable area, css attributes do not.  Without those attributes, the canvas will be very pixalated.

Comment: @Daedalus is right, the width and height attributes should **not** be removed from the canvas element.

Comment: @Daedalus. Am not familiar with html. But what he provided solves my need and resolves my problem. But i try to adapt what u said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but I see a problem in your code. Change to this...

```
canvas:hover { 
    width: 400;
    height: 400;
}
```

or

```
canvas#myCanvas:hover { 
    width: 400;
    height: 400;
}
```